# many to many relationship in mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm writing a small torrent indexer in Ruby ([here](http://github.com/tekknolagi/indexer)) and would love to support MongoDB as an option for the database. Currently, I have the database set up with a many-to-many relationship between `tag`s and `torrent`s.

How would I format a query that gets all the `torrent_id`s from a map table that match to all the tags in a given list?

I did this in SQL like this:

`select torrent_id, count(*) num from tagmap where tag_id in (tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4) group by torrent_id having num = 4"`

EDIT: I am right now working only with the collection with `torrent_id` and `tag_id`. That's all it has in there. So I'm mapping ids to ids and naught more.

Comment: You should consider not having a joining collection and just putting the tags directly into your torrent collection.

Comment: What are the advantages of each over the other?

Comment: If you have a joining collection, you'll need to do multiple queries to relate the tags and the torrent records. If you have the tags directly in the records, in an array, for example, you'll be able to just search for torrents with a particular tag in a single query.

Comment: What about the disadvantages of the direct association?

Comment: Disadvantages, hmm. Might take more space if the tags are pretty long, I suppose--but they'd have to be bigger than 24 bytes at least, probably a bit more. That's probably not much sacrifice for the performance of a single query.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm just planning on having as many options as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to create a collection to create the mapping consisting tag_id's and torrent_id's. Whenever you add a torrent, also add the torrents tags to the torrenttags collection. Index should be on tag_id.

You can use the following query syntax to get a list of torrents matching more than one tag.

`db.tagmap.find({tag_id:{$in: ['tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4']}});`

For [Aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Examples) (group by, count) you need to use MapReduce

Comment: Oh, is that the same as the Ruby syntax? Would it work as `$map.find(:tag => {:$in => ['tag1','tag2']})` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Ruby driver, but it seems valid to me.

Comment: [MongoDB Find Syntax for Ruby](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method)